# Should IntelliSense complain about template variables?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, intellisense

I've tried out template variables in VC++ (with all the latest updates installed to this point) and got everything compiled and working (it says that `item` is not used, well, quite legitimate warning on level 4)! The only bad thing is that *IntelliSense* is complaining about the template variables.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct Whatever
{};

struct Bottle
{};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_bottle = false;

template <>
constexpr bool is_bottle<Bottle> = true;

template <typename Item>
void use(Item item)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_bottle <Item> << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    use(Whatever{});
    use(Bottle{});
}
```

For the specialization for `Bottle` IntelliSense complains that

> Explicit specialization of the template variable must precede it's first use ()

(it has the brackets too).

**Question:** is everything meant to be the way they are? I mean template variables working and Intellisense complaining about them.

Comment: A buggy compiler aide is not a good substitute for knowing and understanding C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I know, but I just wanted to check if magical things are not happening, and I'm without sleep like 20 hours.

Comment: This doesn't compile in Visual Studio, you get compiler errors. IntelliSense only gives you hints, it's different.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I've got it compiling and working correctly as was mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: @Olzhas sorry I was mistaken, it does compile, but you do get compiler warnings

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, compiler is silent. It is only IntelliSense complaining

Comment: Put compiler warning on level 4

Comment: Is it the level on which it complains about library headers? Sorry I don't have a compiler at hand now

Comment: No, that's enable all warning (/Wall), level 4 is one below that.